# После обновления страницы должен открыться div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня такая штука, после добавления товара в корзина страница перезагружается и в корзине есть товар. Я хочу что бы после перезагрузки выпадал выпадающий список для пользователя.

Как это реализовывается???
Добавления в корзину

```
<a class="add-to-cart add-cart" data-id="<?= $topSale['id'] ?>"
                       href="<?= Url::to(['product/view', 'id' => $topSale['id']]) ?>">в корзину</a>
```

сам выподающий список с товаркой

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
 список товаров в козине
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с откуда он должен выпадать?

Comment: Можно простой имитацией клика на меню, если в его коде не предусмотрен метод для раскрытия

Comment: @Cheg или просто использовать функцию при загрузке страницы, только после проверки, есть ли товары в корзине.

Comment: а как это реализовывается в js, честно говоря я не бум бум, помогите с кодом

Comment: товар в корзине хранится в куки?

Comment: нет в сессии!!!